# What game is Internet Archive using to represent their MS-DOS collection?

Tags: game-identification, msdos

On the [Internet Archive's news blog](https://blog.archive.org/2019/10/13/2500-more-ms-dos-games-playable-at-the-archive/), they use the following screenshot to represent MS-DOS gaming:

[image]

What game is this from? TinEye and Google Images only return the archive.org page as a result.

Answer (score 13):

I've found the game: it's **Frankenstein** (1994) by Merit Studios. This is the MS-DOS platformer, not the adventure game based on the movie that came out the same time. This is the first screen you see when starting the game:

[image]

It's on [MobyGames](https://www.mobygames.com/game/dos/frankenstein_____/screenshots/gameShotId,736444/), but I'm guessing I wasn't getting any matches when I searched because of the colour cycling used in the background.

How I found it: After manipulating the image from archive.org a few times, I got TinEye to give me a second match linking to a user's favourites on a Russian game website. The game page was 404 but the name 'frankenstein' was in the URL and I found the game from looking that up.